# It's possible to make a uitableviewcell draggable

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, drag-and-drop

[image: My Nib file]

and I want to make the tableviewcells draggable, but outsite the tableview.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe you can make drag the cell outside of it's containing view, but it is possible to create a view on top of the tableview and drag that where you want it. You'd probably want to delete the cell from the table as soon as the user selected the cell to make it look like he grabbed the cell from the table.

Comment: do you have any suggestion on how to mac this?

Comment: I'd start by recreating the cell view over the selected cell in `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath`, followed by promptly deleting the cell from the table. That will give the user the impression they have "grabbed" the cell. After that it's a matter of moving the view by following the touch events. Unfortunately I don't have any experience with custom touch events - I'll look into when I get a chance, hopefully sometime tomorrow. Let me know if you figure it out!

Comment: Also, check out the `center` property of UIView, I think it will be helpful:[http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html]